# Where to learn more about custom consensus implementation?

Tags: consensus

Any tips, links and examples to go deep with custom consensus implementation?

I like to create a very light consensus where the majority of the node are well known nodes and I want to implement checks on their work, from an external more resilient blockchain, only one time every x blocks.

Comment: Checkout these playlist from Seun https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lICQD3FMAZw&list=PLLBglgxW6ibJ6tUDKEcPY0GUia4wgd-Sx&index=22,  You will know which Traits needs to be implemented for Consensus

Comment: Thanks I take a look!